# IIS Getting 403.16 error when Client certificates option is set to "Accept"

Tags: iis, client-certificates, iis-10, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

We have a webapi application hosted on IIS 10. Apart from token based authentication, we also support client certificate based authentication. To support client cert based auth, we have the client certificate setting in IIS set to **Accept**. So the consumer has to either send a certificate or token to authenticate.

One of our customers is integrating the APIs with Oracle CPQ and using tokens to authenticate. But they are getting 403.16 error from IIS. Their stand is that they are not sending any certificate with the request. But I suspect that some default client certificate is being sent. How do I find out if that is the case or is there any other problem that I'm missing.

We also have made following registry changes. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution below:

1. On the IIS Web server, select Start, type mmc.exe in the Start Search box, right-click mmc.exe, and then select Run as administrator.
2. On the File menu, select Add/Remove Snap-in.
3. Under Available snap-ins, select Certificates, and then select Add.
4. Select Computer account, and then select Next.
5. Select Local computer, select Finish, and then select Close.
6. To exit the wizard, select OK.
7. Expand Certificates, expand Trusted Root Certification Authorities, right-click Certificates, point to All Tasks, and then select Import.
8. In the Certificate Import Wizard, select Next.
9. In the File name box, type the location of the root certificate of the certification authority, and then select Next.
10. Select Next, and then select Finish.

Comment: This is not the issue. The problem is that the consumer is denying sending any certificate at all. But this error occurs when they are sending an invalid certificate. How to prove to them that they are sending a certificate and if possible get the details of the certificate like it's issuer, thumbprint etc. Since the control doesn't reach the code, we can't even log it from within the code.

Comment: Move any non-self-signed certificated out of the Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificate store and into the Intermediate Certification Authorities Certificate store.

Comment: that is not the issue. Please read the question and my comment again.

Comment: Please show me the details message about 403.16 error.